# How to set a value to a bean property from a JavaScript async callback

Tags: javascript, facebook, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I need to get data from a Javascript function (Facebook sdk) from `<p:commandLink>`

My code is:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{faceController.getStatuses()}" update="afterLoads" oncomplete="getInfo();">
<h:outputText value="PRUEBA" />
</p:commandLink>
```

My Script is:

```
<h:panelGroup id="afterLoads">
 <h:outputScript>
    function getInfo() {
        FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields:  'first_name,last_name,name,email,id,picture.width(150).height(150)'},  function(response) {
                var a=response.email;
               alert(#{faceController.dato=response.email});

    });

    }

   </h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

My bean is:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FaceController {
     public String dato="";
        public void getStatuses() {
           System.out.println("dato> "+dato);
        }
}
```

I get null data. What is the problem? Help me please!!

Reference:
[Getting backing bean value with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966205/getting-backing-bean-value-with-javascript)

Comment: if i understand you  are trying to set a value to a bean property from your javascript function. Take a look to  [this](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-pass-new-hidden-value-to-backing-bean-in-jsf/) page there are some good examples there.

Comment: HI!!! @David I saw the link but  I can't make it work. The problem is that I can't send data from **function(response)**, which is inside the **function getInfo()**. Any suggestions!!

Comment: add a `<h:inputHidden id="dato" value="#{FaceController.dato}" />`, and a remote command `<p:remoteCommand name="processDato" process="dato" actionListener="#{faceController.getStatuses()}" />`, inside your callback function asign  ´response.email´ to ´dato´ an then call `processDato();`. like this `document.getElementById("yourForm:dato").value = response.email; processDato();`